# Flask teardown request equivalent in Fastapi

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

I am building a rest api with fastapi. I implemented the data layer separately from the fastapi application meaning I do not have direct access to the database session in my fastapi application.

I have access to the storage object which have method like `close_session` which allow me to close the current session.

Is there a equivalent of **flask** `teardown_request` in **fastapi**?

**Flask Implementation**

```py
from models import storage
.....
.....

@app.teardown_request
def close_session(exception=None):
    storage.close_session()
```

I have looked at fastapi `on_event('shutdown')` and `on_event('startup')`. These two only runs when the application is shutting down or starting up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this by using dependency.

**credit to williamjemir**: [Click here to read the github discussion](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/6012)

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends                           
from models import storage
                                                                                                                   
async def close_session() -> None:  
  """Close current after every request."""
  print('Closing current session')
  yield                         
  storage.close()  
  print('db session closed.')

app = FastAPI(dependencies=[Depends(close_session)])                        
                                                                                                                                          
@app.get('/')                                                        
def home():                                                          
   return "Hello World"                                             
                                                                    
if __name__ == '__main__':                                           
  import uvicorn  
  uvicorn.run(app)
```

Answer (score 1):

## use fastapi middleware

> A "middleware" is a function that works with every request before it is processed by any specific path operation. And also with every response before returning it.

- It takes each request that comes to your application.
- It can then do something to that request or run any needed code.
- Then it passes the request to be processed by the rest of the application (by some path operation).
- It then takes the response generated by the application (by some path operation).
- It can do something to that response or run any needed code.
- Then it returns the response.

Example:

```py
import time

from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI()


@app.middleware("http")
async def add_process_time_header(request: Request, call_next):
    # do things before the request
    response = await call_next(request)
    # do things after the response
    return response
```

### references:

- https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/middleware/